# Add line for mean per day (ggplot)

Tags: r

I have a dataset on views for web pages, the below is an example. The dataset extends until August. UPV is unique page views.

```
Datum      Page                  UPV 
  <date>     <fct>               <int>  
1 2020-03-16 Page1                  548  
2 2020-03-16 Page2                  355  
3 2020-03-16 Page3                  140    
4 2020-03-17 Page2                  883  
5 2020-03-17 Page1                  337  
6 2020-03-17 Page3                  76
```

I have been able to create facet plots for for the individual factor levels with:

```
ggplot(webviews, aes(Datum, UPV, col=Page)) + geom_col(width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + facet_wrap(Page ~ .) + theme_bw()+ 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  # Facet grid
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(
      color="#535353", fill="black", size=.004, linetype="solid"))+ theme( 
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "grey", face="bold")) + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(
    title = "\n Title \n", caption = "Caption \n") + 
  theme (
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme (
    plot.title = element_text(color = "grey", size = 12, face = "bold"), 
    plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "grey"), 
    plot.caption = element_text(color = "#696969", size = 7, face = "italic", hjust=0.5))
```

So far, this is ok. Still playing around with plot result itself.

I'd like to add an element here to each of these plots: a line for the mean UPV (of all pages) for each day, so you can easily see whether the pages scores above or below the mean for that day. I've tried this, but I haven't bent able to connect this df, to the original plots:

```
webviews_mean <- webviews %>% group_by(Datum) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(UPV))
```

I hope it's a bit clear what I'm trying to do here... I'm still new to this and a bit brainfried from trying things. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean a horizontal line for each page across all facets?

Comment: Hi Justin - just a little tip on making it easier for people to answer your question: calling the `dput()` function probably just on the `head()` of your `webviews` table and pasting the output of that into your question will allow people to reproduce the `webviews` object in their sessions with less typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest an approach as next:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
webviews <- structure(list(Datum = c("16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "16/03/2020", 
"17/03/2020", "17/03/2020", "17/03/2020"), Page = c("Page1", 
"Page2", "Page3", "Page2", "Page1", "Page3"), UPV = c(548L, 355L, 
140L, 883L, 337L, 76L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Code:

```
#Aggregate for means
webviews_mean <- webviews %>% group_by(Page) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(UPV)) %>% ungroup()
#Plots
ggplot(webviews, aes(Datum, UPV, col=Page)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  geom_hline(data = webviews_mean,aes(yintercept = Mean),color='white',lty='dashed')+
  facet_wrap(Page ~ .) + theme_bw()+ 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"), panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  # Facet grid
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(
      color="#535353", fill="black", size=.004, linetype="solid"))+ theme( 
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "grey", face="bold")) + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(
    title = "\n Title \n", caption = "Caption \n") + 
  theme (
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme (
      plot.title = element_text(color = "grey", size = 12, face = "bold"), 
      plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "grey"), 
      plot.caption = element_text(color = "#696969", size = 7, face = "italic", hjust=0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

The dashed lines show the averages across each facet. For sure you could modify that.

Comment: Your answer got me on track! I actually ended up using

webviews_mean <- webviews %>% group_by(Datum) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(UPV))

Comment: @Justin Fantastic, as `ggplot2` was tagged in the title of the question I did the sketch for a plot. I hope that helped you in any sense!

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incomplete.

UPV_mean <- webviews %>% group_by(Datum) %>%
  summarize(Mean = mean(UPV))

To get the average per day. Then added it to the graph with + geom_point(data = UPV_mean, aes(y=Mean), color='#696969', size=4, shape="-") and now I have the general average per date in the graph. So thanks for you help!

Comment: @Justin Great ! If you think this answer was useful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer! It is up to you :)